# new Date() doesn't work with canvasjs & rangeBar

Tags: php, json, canvas, canvasjs

I tried to read some datas with AJAX json format from PHP code.

```
.../...
    $data[]     = array("label" => $my_label, "y" => array("new Date($yci,$mci,$dci,$hci,$ici)","new Date($yco,$mco,$dco,$hco,$ico)"));
}

return json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Side JS

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("timeline", {
    title: {
        text: "How long an event occurred for on a given day"
    },
    axisY: {
        minimum: (new Date(2017, 5, 1, 00, 01)).getTime(),            
        interval: (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 7 ),
        labelFormatter: function(e){
        return CanvasJS.formatDate(e.value, "MM/DD");
        },
        gridThickness: 1
    },

    toolTip:{
        contentFormatter: function ( e ) {
        return "<strong>" + e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong></br> Start: " +  CanvasJS.formatDate(e.entries[0].dataPoint.y[0], "DD - h:mm TT") + "</br>End : " + CanvasJS.formatDate(e.entries[0].dataPoint.y[1], "DD - h:mm TT");  
    }},

    data: [
    {
      type: "rangeBar",
    dataPoints: JSON.parse(json.message),
    }
    ]                      
});
chart.render();

}
```

The issue is, unable to display the datas. 
I think new date is not formated correctely.

```
[
{
    "label":"Room 200",
    "y":
         [
            "new Date(2017,5,06,14,20)",
            "new Date(2017,5,08,14,20)"
         ]
 },
 {
    "label":"Room 200",
    "y":
        [
            "new Date(2017,5,08,14,21)",
            "new Date(2017,5,10,14,21)"
        ]
},
{
    "label":"Room 201",
    "y":
        [
            "new Date(2017,5,11,15,59)",
            "new Date(2017,5,13,15,59)"
        ]
}
]
```

Also, something is weird with new date() from canvasjs sample, at the end of each code, there's **.getTime()** like this : **new date().getTime()**

http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/xqgja576/

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The y values you have provided in array are strings ("new Date(2017,5,06,14,20)"). To evaluate this y value as date you can use eval function. Also, CanvasJS doesn't support dateTime over yAxis. As a workaround, you can call getTime() to fetch it's time-stamp and set it to y values.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < dataPoints[i].y.length; j++) {
    y = eval(dataPoints[i].y[j]);
    //if(y.getTime)
    dataPoints[i].y[j] = y.getTime();
  }
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boh2Lh99/) with your code and the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass dates from back-end as UTC timestamps, so, you woldn't need any client-side conversions:

```
$start = new \DateTime("$yci/$mci/$dci $hci:$ici", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$end = new \DateTime("$yco/$mco/$dco $hco:$ico", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$data[] = array(
    "label" => $my_label, 
    "y" => array(
        // don't forget for '*1000 part' to convert
        // from unix timestamp (seconds) to UTC timestamp (milliseconds)
        $start->getTimestamp() * 1000,
        $end->getTimestamp() * 1000,
     ),
);
```

Also, you need to account for proper `DateTime` object initialization based on your code (maybe, you already have date-time objects somewhere earlier in your's code and just deconstructed them to `$yci, $mci, $dci, $hci, $ici` variables for convenience). You can use [this](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.construct.php) man page as a reference.

Comment: Yeah issue fixed
    .../...
    $data[]     = array("label" => $my_label, "y" => array($dci,$dco));
}

Comment: $dci and $dco having as content a timestamp value and the array need to be integer and not striing.
it works fine now.

Comment: Thanks at all. ;)

Comment: Glad it helped =)